# Trying to list all s3 buckets under that role name or IAM role arn This is my code. Nothing is populating

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    with open('input.json', 'r') as file:
        input_data = json.load(file)
    role_name = input_data['role_name']
    session = boto3.Session()
    iam_client = session.client('iam')
    response = iam_client.list_role_tags(RoleName=role_name)
    users = []
    buckets = []

    for tag in response['Tags']:
        if tag['Key'] == 'UserName':
            users.append(tag['Value'])

        if tag['Key'] == 's3:accessPointArn':
            bucket_arn = tag['Value']
            bucket_name = bucket_arn.split(':')[-1]
            buckets.append(bucket_name)

 
    print(bucket)
    print(user)
```

I ran the script and nothing is happening. It is returning o result. I want to see all s3 buckets under that role passed in the json file.

Comment: What are buckets "under" a role? That terminology makes little / no sense.

Comment: "nothing is happening". Do you mean the command hangs, or nothing is printed? Others have mentioned the syntax error, but if your actual code is correct, and the command is returning nothing, then I would guess this means that the role has no tags?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When attempting to debug an AWS Lambda function, you can view the output in Amazon CloudWatch. In the Lambda console, open your function and click the **Monitoring** tab. Then click **View Logs in CloudWatch**. It should display your output or an error message (in this case, it should show that the `bucket` variable is not defined).

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the print statements.
The variables are:

```
users = []
buckets = []
```

but in the print statements it is:

```
print(bucket)
print(user)
```

The correct variables are not called in the print statements, so you are not getting any outputs. Hope this helps.